# Typescript Dictionary failing to perform

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a very simple Typescript definition for a "dictionary" which looks like this:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

I then use this Interface in another interface definition like so:

```
interface IGatewayInput {
  queryParameters: IDictionary<string>;
  body?: string;
}
```

I then have a function which receives the `IGatewayInput`:

```
doSomething( input: IGatewayInput ) {
  if(input.queryParameters.oauth_token) {
    // ....
  }
}
```

but while I'd expect the dictionary to allow "queryParameters" to have any key value I instead get the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'oauth_token' does not exist on type 'IDictionary'.'

What am I doing wrong? I thought my definition would allow for any string based key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined an "indexable type" ([typescript reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)) which can be used as an array indexer:

```
if (input.queryParameters['oauth_token']) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I do not know how you are testing, but this code definitely must work! what  typescript compiler version are you using?

Comment: so I definitely figure it *should* work and actually whether you use bracket notation like you suggest above or just dot notation ... either one should work.

Comment: ok this is odd, fully caffeinated, I tried this again and with the bracket based signature it *was* ok but with dot-notation it still gives the error. I guess I'll mark this as the correct answer. I'm a bit surprised that dot notation doesn't work exactly the same as brackets. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can amend your dictionary runtime, I don't think there is any way you can get it statically compiled(i.e. the compiler won't ever know this property exists).

I think you should use either a specific interface/class or `any` to do it.

Comment: I don't need it to know that a particular property exists but rather that there will be set of properties (who's name I _do not know_ which will be defined with string values).

Comment: I mean you are accessing the property here: `input.queryParameters.oauth_token`. How would a compiler know that `oauth_token` token exists? So that's why I think it's not possible to do this way unless you have `any` type for variable.

Comment: It very common to be given an options hash which has name-value pairs where the names are not known at compile time. This is the basis of the use case and the important thing is _not_ to predict that the `oauth_token` property will be used but to annotate that any name/value pair on the Object is to be allowed.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see why you can't just use `any` since you can't get any statical benefits on it anyway?

Comment: I want to define `queryParameters` as an **Object** but not have TS warn me about properties that hang off it (since there will be properties but they can't be typed at compile time). The main point is about being explicit about it being an Object and not just *any*thing. I also want to be able to define what the type of the values are.